# Java Point, difference between getX() and point.x

Tags: java, point

I am confused to as why the Java Point class takes in two int paramaters and the getX() and getY() methods return doubles. 
For example I could define a Point

```
Point p = new Point(4,6);
```

If I were to call..

```
p.getX();
```

It would return 4.0. and if I were to call

```
p.x;
```

I would get 4.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Mostly, it's because of backwards compatibility and the fact that `Point` has been hacked together over a relatively long period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `Point2D.Double` and `Point2D.Float` classes that extend `Point2D` which is a superclass of `Point` and they need to be able to work with floating point values. Note that there is also a `setLocation( double, double )`.

`Point2D` is an abstract class that implements the distance calculation for points, and `setLocation`, `getX`, and `getY` are its abstract methods, which is why they all use `doubles` and why `Point` has to implement them with `double`s in the signature.

Comment: Strange how you must initialize both x and y to ints, but then can set the location of x and y to doubles.

Comment: `setLocation` in the `Point` class will round it to the nearest integers, so a `Point` always has integer coordinates.