# Should I use Point.x or Point.getX()?

Tags: java, point, getter

I have a `Point`.  I am trying to get `x` as an `int`.  If I use `Point.x`, I will get `x` as an `int`.  But I am under the impression that I should be using a getter whenever possible ([Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)).  The issue with [`Point.getX()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#getX--) is that it returns a double instead of an int.

Which is better, or is it just preference?

`a` or `b`?

```
Point point = new Point(5, 5);
int a = point.x;
int b = (int) point.getX();
```

I have read [Java Point, difference between getX() and point.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221327/java-point-difference-between-getx-and-point-x), but it did not really answer my question.  Or at least I did not understand the answer.

Comment: I use `point.x`. It's not *your* fault that `Point` is broken. :-) It's not like your code will evolve to work with a sub-/super type of Point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getX()` and `getY()` functions of the `Point` class return a double because that's what its parent class ([Point2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html)) requires. This is so all of its subclasses ([Point2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) and [Point2D.Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Float.html)) will all work in the same places.

Using `point.x` and `point.y` directly instead of using the getter functions is probably fine in this case, since the Point class is a weird corner case that nobody seems to love- most people think it should be immutable, or at least better hide its values.

If you're afraid of something like a code review, just throw a comment in there explaining why you're accessing the x and y variables directly.

tl;dr: it just comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in short, that the designers of this class didn't want to create another couple of functions getXAsInteger and getYAsInteger, but still give you the option to get the underlying integer values, instead of the values converted to double. So make an exception in that case and use the fields directly.

Answer (score 1):

As the `double` return type of the getter methods of  point class is only to make it compatible through the inheritance and the `getX()` do nothing without just returning value.

SO, Its just about your preference, I guess.
But like use `point.x` (why making the unnecessary conversion? ) in this case only, Although I prefer using getter/setter always.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in other answers: The inheritance hierarchy of `Point2D` is ... somewhat unusual. The reason for that is simple:

From the documentation of [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html):

> A point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space, specified in integer precision.
>
> **Since:** 1.0

From the documentation of [`Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html):

> The Point2D class defines a point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space.
>
> **Since:**
> 1.2

Simply put: The `Point` class existed since the beginning of time, and the `Point2D` class was introduced later. The `Point` class has then been "retrofitted" to also be a `Point2D`, and offer the `getX()` methods, for example.

---

When you are working with `Point`, and dedicatedly **only** with `Point`, and you **always** and **only** want to deal with `int` coordinates, then you can use `point.x` to access the field directly.

Otherwise, when double coordinates make sense for your application case, and you want, for example, a method that receives a "point" as a parameter, you usually should consider using the abstract `Point2D` class, because then you can pass a `Point`, a `Point2D.Double` or a `Point2D.Float` instance to this method.